# Cygwin find integration

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, cygwin, find

I would like to find all NON read-only files in my directory using cygwin's find command.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cygwin maps windows file attributes to unix file permissions.
So this command works to find all non read-only files:

```
find . -type f -perm -u+w
```

Comment: In Cygwin 1.7, Unix file permissions map to Windows access control lists (ACLs) rather than ye olde DOS file attributes.